# PDO does not fetch any results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was using PDO queries directly in index.php file.Now I want to create separate file where I will store functions. I created one, but when I call function returns only "0". Old version works:

```
$abfrage11 = "SELECT COUNT(e.event_id) as numgoals
FROM event e 
WHERE (e.match_id = '$row1->match_id' AND e.team_id = '$row1->team_a_id' AND e.eventtype IN ('soc_G','soc_PG') ) OR
      (e.match_id = '$row1->match_id' AND e.team_id = '$row1->team_b_id' AND e.eventtype = 'soc_OG' )";
$ergebnis11 = $dbh->query($abfrage11);
$row11 = $ergebnis11->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

BUt in new version not:

separate file "storage.php":

```
class StorageAccess
{
    /** @var  PDO */
    public $db;

    /**
     * @param $db
     */
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;

    }
public function getAbfrage11()
    {
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(e.event_id) as numgoals
                    FROM event e 
                    WHERE (e.match_id = :mId AND e.team_id = :tmA AND e.eventtype IN ('soc_G','soc_PG') ) OR
                          (e.match_id = :mId2 AND e.team_id = :tmB AND e.eventtype = 'soc_OG' )";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute([
            ':mId' => $row1->match_id,
            ':mId2' => $row1->match_id,
            ':tmA' => $row1->team_a_id,
            ':tmB' => $row1->team_b_id,
        ]);
        return $statement->fetchObject();
    }
}
```

call in index.php:

```
require_once("dblogin.php");
require_once("Storage.php");

$dbFactory = new RepositoriesFactory();
$dbh = $dbFactory->getDataBaseInstance('admgsa_gsa');
$storage_access = new StorageAccess($dbh);

$row11 = $storage_access->getAbfrage11();
echo "<span class='live-monitor-8' style=\"$goalscbgcolor\">$row11->numgoals</span>";
```

Tried to search for the solution, but could not find anything. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't `':mId' => $row1->team_a_id` be `':mId' => $row1->match_id`?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can't reuse the same placeholder.

Comment: @Siguza yes it should be, typo, but still does not return any results.

Comment: Re my previous comment. From the documentation `You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.`

Comment: Used `':mId' => $row1->match_id, ':mId2' => $row1->match_id,` and changed in query also, but did not help.

Comment: Where did you get the `$row1`?

Comment: @JeroenBellemans It is another query in the index.php.

Comment: Hmm never tried it, but does the method not require those variables? Or can the method reach them?

Comment: @JeroenBellemans You mean if method can get `row1` results?

Comment: Yes, try using them as parameters in the method?

Comment: @JeroenBellemans Tried,but have does not do anything. Maybe I am missing something very simple and can not see...

Answer (score -1):

Got what was the problem. I was not specifying input parameter:

```
public function getAbfrage11($row1)
    {
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(e.event_id) as numgoals
                    FROM event e 
                    WHERE (e.match_id = :mId AND e.team_id = :tmA AND e.eventtype IN ('soc_G','soc_PG') ) OR
                          (e.match_id = :mId2 AND e.team_id = :tmB AND e.eventtype = 'soc_OG' )";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute([
            ':mId' => $row1->match_id,
            ':mId2' => $row1->match_id,
            ':tmA' => $row1->team_a_id,
            ':tmB' => $row1->team_b_id,
        ]);
        return $statement->fetchObject();
    }
```

This fixed my problem.